# Unknown source of error in while command in python

Tags: python

I am testing a code written and posted on the website

http://foreverlearning.altervista.org/genetic-programming-symbolic-regression-pt-3/

The portion of the code is located at the bottom part of the webpage.  When running the test code mainpova.py, I am getting the syntax error.

The syntax error is,

```
python mainprova4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mainprova4.py", line 1, in <module>
import generation as gn
File "/home/adam/DocumentsNew2/MathCode/SymbolicRegression/WebpageCode    /generation.py", line 46
while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: indexSelected = 0 while     rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected !=     len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The indicator ' ^ ' is actually located below e of the while word located before rnd.randint.  This is for the portion of the code,

```
def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
""" Returns a certain number of distinct members from the    generation.
The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not chosen, the 
second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
selectedMembers = []
while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: indexSelected = 0 while   rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
        indexSelected += 1
    memberWithErrorSelected =   self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
    if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
        selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
return selectedMembers
```

The source code has been corrected for lesser and greater typos.  Other than that the code is fine except for the while loop.  What is the source for the syntax error?  The website shows what the output should be.

Comment: `while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: indexSelected = 0 while   rnd.randint...` what

Comment: Well, for one thing the code has indentation issues that will cause syntax errors. If it's something other than that, please fix the indentation errors.

Comment: Why do you have all of that on one line?

Comment: Are you missing newlines somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The formatting is still incorrect. It should look like this:

```
def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
    """ Returns a certain number of distinct members from the    generation.
    The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not chosen, the 
    second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
    selectedMembers = []
    while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers:
        indexSelected = 0
        while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
            indexSelected += 1
        memberWithErrorSelected =   self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
        if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
            selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
    return selectedMembers
```

Comment: I was not aware that indentation plays role in python coding.  (I am rookie in python).  Yes, it fixed the problem, but another popped out.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that indentation plays role in python coding.  (I am rookie in python).  Yes, it fixed the problem, but another popped out.  The error is,

```
     python mainprova4.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "mainprova4.py", line 1, in <module>
     import generation as gn
     File "/home/adam/DocumentsNew2/MathCode/SymbolicRegression/WebpageCode /generation.py", line 105, in <module>
      for i in range(0, numCrossover):
      NameError: name 'numCrossover' is not defined
```

The code for this is,

```
import random as rnd
import generator as gtr
import treeOperations as trop

class Generation(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.membersWithErrors = []

def addMember(self, member):
    """ Add a tree to the generation """
    self.membersWithErrors.append([member, 0])

def setMember(self, member, index):
    """ Updates the member at the specified position """
    self.membersWithErrors[index] = member

def setError(self, index, error):
    """ Sets the error of the member at the specified position """
    self.membersWithErrors[index][1] = error

def getMember(self, index):
    """ Returns the member at the specified position """
    return self.membersWithErrors[index][0]

def getError(self, index):
    """ Returns the error of the member at the specified position """
    return self.membersWithErrors[index][1]

def size(self):
    """ Returns the number of members curently in the generation """
    return len(self.membersWithErrors)

def clear(self):
    """ Clears the generation, i.e. removes all the members """
    self.membersWithErrors.clear()

def sort(self, descending):
    """ Sorts the members of the generation according the their score """
    self.membersWithErrors.sort(key = lambda l: l[1], reverse = descending)

def getMembersForReproduction(self, numMembers, pickProb):
""" Returns a certain number of distinct members from the generation.
The first member is selected with probability pickProb. If it's not chosen, the 
second member is selected with probability pickProb, and so on. """
    selectedMembers = []
    while len(selectedMembers) < numMembers: 
        indexSelected = 0  
        while rnd.randint(0, 100) > int(pickProb * 100) and indexSelected != len(self.membersWithErrors) - 1:
    indexSelected += 1
    memberWithErrorSelected = self.membersWithErrors[indexSelected]
    if memberWithErrorSelected[0] not in selectedMembers:
       selectedMembers.append(memberWithErrorSelected[0])
return selectedMembers

def next(self, crossoverPerc, mutationPerc, randomPerc, copyPerc,   shouldPruneForMaxHeight, minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators):
""" It proceeds to the next generation with the help of genetic operations """
oldMembersWithError = self.membersWithErrors
newMembersWithError = []
maxMembers = len(oldMembersWithError)

numCrossover = int(maxMembers * crossoverPerc)
numMutation = int(maxMembers * mutationPerc)
numRandom = int(maxMembers * randomPerc)
numCopy = maxMembers - numCrossover - numMutation - numRandom

# Crossover
for i in range(0, numCrossover):
    members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
    m1 = members[0]
    m2 = members[1]
    newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
    newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])

# Mutation
for i in range(0, numMutation):
    m1 = self.getMembersForReproduction(1, 0.3)[0]
    newMembersWithError.append([trop.mutation(m1, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

# Random
for i in range(0, numRandom):
    newMembersWithError.append([gtr.getTree(minHeight, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables, operators), 0])

# Copy
members = self.getMembersForReproduction(numCopy, 0.3)
for m in members:
    newMembersWithError.append([m.clone(), 0])

self.membersWithErrors = newMembersWithError

# No side effects
def pruneTreeForMaxHeight(tree, maxHeight, minValue, maxValue, variables):
""" Returns a new tree that is like the specified tree
but pruned so that its height is maxHeight """
def pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, counter, minValue, maxValue, variables):
    if tree.height() == 1:
        return tree.clone()
    if counter == maxHeight:
        return gtr.getLeaf(minValue, maxValue, variables)
    pruned1 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op1, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
    pruned2 = pruneTreeAux(tree.op2, maxHeight, counter + 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)
    return tr.BinaryOperatorInternalNode(tree.operator, pruned1, pruned2)
return pruneTreeAux(tree, maxHeight, 1, minValue, maxValue, variables)

# Crossover
for i in range(0, numCrossover):
members = self.getMembersForReproduction(2, 0.3)
m1 = members[0]
m2 = members[1]
newMember = trop.crossover(m1, m2)
if shouldPruneForMaxHeight and newMember.height() > maxHeight:
    newMember = trop.pruneTreeForMaxHeight(newMember, maxHeight, minValue,  maxValue, variables)
newMembersWithError.append([newMember, 0])
```

The numCrossover is already defined.  What I am missing here?

Comment: Its not defined

Comment: This is not the appropriate place to ask another question. Since you've solved your original issue, accept an answer to complete this question. Then if you're not able to resolve your new issue on your own, ask it as a new question.

Comment: Also, a tip for pasting code into questions/answers: after pasting, immediately select what you just pasted and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface. Then you won't have to try to manually fix the formatting.

Comment: Very well, thanks for feedback.  I will post another question as required.  I appreciate the tip about pasting.  This is always a struggle for me especially if I want paste in comments section instead answering my own questions.